# How to display the value of date in the date and time picker box on the datagrid view when double clicked

Tags: c#, sql, datetimepicker

I got this code here. All of the textboxes are working except for the datetime picker box. I just want to display the records to the textboxes and datetime picker box when the record is double clicked. Please help.

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Employee2 where [Employee ID] = " + (dgData.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString()) + " ", con);
            da.Fill(dt);

            textBox1.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
            textBox2.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
            dtPicker.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") = dt.Rows[0][2];
            textBox4.Text = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString();
            textBox5.Text = dt.Rows[0][4].ToString();

            displayRecords();
```

Answer (score 0):

I Assume that your 3rd column(Date column) is of `DateTime` type in your table.

**Problem :** You are not properly assigning the `Value` to the `DateTimePicker` control.

Try This:

```
dtPicker.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0][2]);
/*set the custom format now*/
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
dateTimePicker1.Format =DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
```